# Get-AssociatedTeam cmdlet does not accept an array of user identities as a parameter. So what does?

Tags: list, powershell, microsoft-teams

Trying to pull a list of all associated users within a department and create a new list that groups those users associated with their respective teams and organize it by department.
I tried to use Get-AssociatedTeam with an array of users in a specific department and it said I could only use the cmdlet one user at a time. Problem is I have to organize a list for about 300 users by department and that would take too long. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
# Import Modules 
Connect-MicrosoftTeams 

# List of users 
$userIds = "Example.DomainName.com", "Example.DomainName.com", "Example.DomainName.com"


# Iterate through the list and retrieve associated teams for each user 
foreach ($userId in $userIds) {
    # Retrieve the Teams associated with the user 
    $teams = Get-AssociatedTeam -User $userIds

    # Display the Teams associated with the user
    Write-Host "Teams associated with user: $userId"
    $teams
    Write-Host

}
```

And the error I'm receiving:

```
Get-AssociatedTeam : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'User'. Specified 
method is not supported.
At line:11 char:39
+     $teams = Get-AssociatedTeam -User $userIds
+                                       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AssociatedTeam], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Teams.PowerShell.TeamsCmdlets.GetAssociatedTeam
```

Comment: Kindly share your piece of code that you have tried. Also share us some sample user identities , how are you taking the input, etc.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add my script.

Comment: The error is due to a typo: `-User $userIds` ->  `-User $userId`

Comment: @maxdj2k - Have you check with changing below code :
 -User $userIds -> -User $userId

Comment: @mklement0 @Nivedipa-MSFT Yes, I did change it but ran into another error:                        ```                                                                                                                                  Get-AssociatedTeam : Error occurred while executing 
Code: Forbidden
Message: Invalid UserId. UserId does not match Access token UserObjectId                 ```

Comment: @maxdj2k - Could you please try with correct UserId? Check with another UserId.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I actually rewrote the script and got the data I wanted. Instead of writing an array of users as a variable, I used Get-ADUser in active directory to sort it out by associated users in a department automatically and used department users as a variable to make it into a filtered group. I appreciate your help very much though.

Comment: @maxdj2k - Glad to hear that your issue is resolved.